# Как сохранить кнопку с анимацией во всех проверках?

Tags: ios, objective-c

У меня есть кнопка в Interface Builder. И проверка

```
if (check == 0) {

}
if (check == 1) {

}
```

В первой проверке по нажатию на кнопку выполняется анимация(кнопка исчезает) Но во второй проверке кнопка не появляется. Как сохранить кнопку с анимацией во всех проверках?

```
 -(IBAction)ButtonAction:(id)sender
{

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
[_button setAlpha:0];
[UIView commitAnimations];
_Answer.hidden = NO;
}
```

Comment: Тут ошибка в другом. Вы либо не задаете значение `check`, либо не правильно выполняете анимацию во втором случае (тут может быть уйма проблем), так что выложите весь код анимации, пожалуйста.

Comment: Добавил к вопросу

Comment: Ну а теперь жди ответа, я только Java и Pascal знаю :З.

Comment: а что должно происходить? в первой должна исчезать, а во второй появляться обратно? `IBAction` происходит по нажатию на кнопку? а когда происходят проверки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы выставляете ей  `[_button setAlpha:0];` - это и прячет кнопку. То есть вы делаете кнопку полностью прозрачной, можно применить ваш код анимации, только сделать уже `[_button setAlpha:1];` - это вернет вашу кнопку на место. А вообще, узнайте что такое alpha и как с ней работать. К ней можно было бы, например, обратиться вот так - `_button.alpha = 1;`

Comment: Тогда кнопка остается на месте. А мне нужно чтобы она исчезла, если на нее нажать в одной проверке. А если перейти к следующей она снова появилась

Comment: @user193011 Вы меня не так поняли, когда вам нужно что бы кнопка была, ставьте _button.alpha = 1; если вам нужно ее спрятать  _button.alpha = 0;